# What are the consequences of Trump lying on a financial disclosure form?

Tags: united-states, law, donald-trump, campaign-finance

The media are currently full of articles, like [this one](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/plum-line/wp/2018/05/15/the-truth-is-about-to-catch-up-to-trump-he-has-giuliani-to-thank-for-it/) saying that D.J. Trump could be in trouble for not disclosing payments to Stormy Daniels.

Without getting into details of who did or did not do what, what are the (legal) consequences if he is shown to have filled a knowingly inaccurate and misleading financial disclosure form? None of the articles say.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Law.SE

Comment: Hmmm, I am actually interested in both the political and legal consequences, but can't ask the same question twice. Can you help me to rephrase it? E.g, the political consequences might be impeachment, or withdrawal of some political privilege, which has further political ramifications ...

Comment: there's no concept of "withdrawal of political privilege" in US politics (unless you mean some sort of fines for finance campaign violations, but that is 100% legal question). And impeachment was already extensively covered on this site in existing answers (TL:DR: "doesn't matter what President did or didn't do. Impeachment is whatever Congress decides is worth impeaching for, as a *political* decision)

Comment: @user4012 : "there's no concept of "withdrawal of political privilege" in US politics" -> yes there is : https://www.hrw.org/legacy/reports98/vote/usvot98o.htm#FELONY

Comment: @Evargalo - I don't think that was what OP meant. They were talking about his "political priviledge" in the role as a President, not as a private citizen.

Comment: Yes. that's what I meant (+1).  Like when they took away Jared's security clearance (bad analogy, I know). Could being caught at that remove some privilege, which might have further consequences.

Comment: @Mawg No, the President is the President until he is impeached or leaves office for some other reason.

Comment: I see (+1). So it's not like they would revoke his canteen privileges or something? I guess then that this is more of a legal question, if there can be no political penalty if he is found to have lied on that form.

Comment: I'm not quite confident enough to make this an answer, but I believe that the article is incorrect in it's understanding of the financial disclosure.  In most parts of the goverment at least the Financial Disclosure only require reporting liability that exist at the end of the year, not liability held during the year that was paid off.  Since trump could have easily payed off the debt during the year that would mean that trump would not have to disclose anything on the financial disclosure.  Thus Trump can report nothing about it this year and not be lying (or at least can't be proven to be)

Comment: Other articles explicitly contradict you view and state that any debt of over 10k during the period must be declared, even if already repaid

Comment: @user4012, *"Impeachment is whatever..."*: any given job can be neglected, but (aside from ceremonial roles) negligence is never a job. If the public believes that its congress failed to impeach a president who needed to be impeached, the option of electing a better congress is never more than two years away.

Comment: Well, it looks like a moot point now, as he declared it (possibly to avoid whatever the consequences might have been?)

Comment: @agc - yes, that's how US political system is supposed to work (in theory). I fail to see how that either answers the question being asked OR affects my point that the answer to question being asked is already discussed elsewhere on the site and is exactly "whatever they decide"

Comment: @user4012, Conflating verdict and crime is inexact.  Impunity has consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question--and not opine on the conclusions of the WaPo reporter whether the details of President Trump's civil matter factually  warrant such a claim-- the Federal Election Commission has a [FAQ page](https://transition.fec.gov/ans/answers_compliance.shtml) that contains answers on penalties.  It reads:

> What penalties can the FEC impose for violations of the law?
>   Most violations of the Federal Election Campaign Act (FECA) result in civil penalties--fines arrived at through a conciliation process. Knowing and willful violations of certain FECA provisions can lead to imprisonment. The FEC has exclusive civil enforcement authority, and may refer criminal violations to the U.S. Department of Justice. For additional information see our page describing the complaint process. Note that sentencing guidelines for criminal violations of the law are set by the U.S. Sentencing Commission.

If this was a filing error, it most certainly would fall under the [Administrative Fines Program](https://www.fec.gov/legal-resources/enforcement/administrative-fines/)  Criminal violations are reserved for matters like embezzlement.

Comment: There is difference between "a filing error" and "[filing] a knowingly inaccurate and misleading financial disclosure form."